# Twilio client - outgoing call play - custom ring tone

Tags: javascript, twilio

I would like to play a custom ring tone until the other party answers the call. I have setup custom sound for outgoing call like this.

```
 Twilio.Device.setup(response, {   sounds: {            
        outgoing: 'https://www.example.com/GDixon-9-Audio-mix.mp3'}});
```

It plays the custom sound for few seconds and then plays the standard tone till the call is answered.

Is it possible to override the standard ringtone completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The standard tone comes from the telephone network itself, or Twilio's connection to it, so it can't be completely customised.

You can choose the country ring tone you want to use if you so desire though. You can achieve this with the [`ringTone` attribute on `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-ring-tone), which you can set to any of the following two letter country codes: at, au, bg, br, be, ch, cl, cn, cz, de, dk, ee, es, fi, fr, gr, hu, il, in, it, lt, jp, mx, my, nl, no, nz,ph, pl, pt, ru, se, sg, th, uk, us, us-old, tw, ve, za.